# When using KIF test framework UIButton is not working for UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, kif-framework, kif

I try to make some scenarios with the KIF framework. When I adding for example:

```
[scenario addStep:[KIFTestStep stepToTapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"MyUIButtonAccessibilityLabel"]];
```

the UIControlEventTouchUpInside is not fired for the UIButton with accessibilityLabel @"MyUIButtonAccessibilityLabel".

Is uigesturerecognizer interfering with the UIControlEventTouchUpInside in KIF? Is there a work-around for this in KIF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ran into this yesterday. stepToTapViewWithAccessibilityLabel has worked just fine for everything in my app, but I encountered a button that it just absolutely won't work for.

To work around it, I ended up using stepToTapScreenAtPoint (which I don't especially like), but it seems to work fine. I also added a void initialize method to my category so that I can determine which device is executing the tests at run-time and based on that, figure out where exactly I need to tap:

```
@implementation KIFTestStep (SLAdditions)

static CGPoint kButtonLocation;

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        kButtonLocation = CGPointMake(498.0, 622.0);
    else
        kButtonLocation = CGPointMake(247.0, 316.0);
}

+ (NSArray *)stepsToDoSomething
{
    NSMutableArray *steps = [NSMutableArray array];

    [steps addObject:[KIFTestStep stepToWaitForTappableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"The Button Label"]];
    [steps addObject:[KIFTestStep stepToTapScreenAtPoint:kButtonLocation]];

    // Verify that tapping succeeded
    [steps addObject:[KIFTestStep stepToWaitForAbsenceOfViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"The Button Label"]];

    return steps;
}
```